# populating a dynamic form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

I am trying to get a forloop with input elements to run between a form and create a form dynamically with javascript

1: in scenario one , the form in the script is getting closed before the input elements populate.

2: in scenario two , when i put the for loop variable between the form ,the error that comes is undefined .

PLEASE HELP

## SCENARIO ONE

```
<form>
No of Feilds <input type="text" id= "numberoffeilds">
<input type="button" value = "Create Feilds" onclick= "addfeilds1();"> 
</form>

<div id= "div4" style= "color:gray"></div> 


<script>

function addfeilds1()
{
   var totalfeilds = document.getElementById("numberoffeilds").value;
   var i;

   document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += '<form action= "issue.html" method = "POST">';

   for(i=0;i<totalfeilds;i++)
   {
       document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += '<input type = "text">';
   }

   document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += '<input type = "submit" value="submit" name="submit">';

}
</script>
```

## SCENARIO TWO

```
<form>
No of Feilds <input type="text" id= "numberoffeilds">
<input type="button" value = "Create Feilds" onclick= "addfeilds2();"> 
</form>

<div id= "div4" style= "color:gray"></div> 

<script>
   function addfeilds2()
   {
      var totalfeilds = document.getElementById("numberoffeilds").value;
      var i;

      function forloop()
      {
          for(i=1 ;i<totalfeilds;i++)
          {
               document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += '<input type = "text">';
          }
      }

      var loopvar = forloop();

      document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML += '<form action= "issue.html" method = "POST">'+
      '<input type = "text">'+
      loopvar + // it shows the loop as undefined
     '<input type = "text">'+
     '<input type = "text">'+
     '<input type = "submit" value="submit" name="submit">';

   }
</script>
```

Comment: am new to using stackoverflow , wat i wanted to imply is to differenciate it as 2 diff scenarios .. can i edit this . ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the HTML elements in a string first and add them to the div as a last step.

Fixed scenario 1:

```
function addfeilds1()
{
   var totalfeilds = document.getElementById("numberoffeilds").value;
   var i;

   var htmlString = "";
   htmlString += '<form action= "issue.html" method = "POST">';

   for(i=0;i<totalfeilds;i++)
   {
       htmlString += '<input type = "text">';
   }

   htmlString += '<input type = "submit" value="submit" name="submit">';
   document.getElementById("div4").innerHTML = htmlString;
}
```

This prevents the form tag from being closed before it's populated with inputs.

Fixing scenario 2:

```
  function forloop()
  {
      var htmlString = "";
      for(i=1 ;i<totalfeilds;i++)
      {
           htmlString  += '<input type = "text">';
      }
      return htmlString; // now forloop returns a string that can be added to the element. It no longers returns undefined.
  }
```

Actually scenario 2 was fixing scenario 1, but you didn't include a return in your function. If you expect a function to create some text and concat that into a string you need your function to return a string.

Third example (advanced)

```
function addfeilds1()
{
    var totalFields = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberoffeilds").value); //parse integer from value
    if (isNaN(totalFields) || totalFields < 1)
    {
        //check if the input is valid, if not alert.
        alert("Value is not a valid number or lower than 1.");
    }

    var container = document.getElementById("div4");
    //create the form     
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "issue.html");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");

    for(var i=0; i<totalFields; ++i)
    {
       var node = document.createElement("input");
       node.setAttribute("name", "field[]"); //this sends a array to the request page containing all input field values.
       form.appendChild(node); //add the fields to the form.
    }

    //create the submit button.
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    button.setAttribute("value", "submit");
    button.setAttribute("name", "submit");
    form.appendChild(button);

    container.appendChild(form); //append the form to the div.
}
```

Comment: awesome dude , its working now .. kewlll ... thanks a zillion bro .. this is extremely helpful .. ,thanks again ..

Comment: @Sebastian take a look at solution 3, it's a very clean one.

Comment: thanks again bro ... the third solution ...is something that i will  have to spend some time with ... cause its a lil advanced for me right now (am new to programing), but your answers have given me so many new things to learn about .... thanks for guiding me in the right direction :)

Comment: Thats the way to learn fast. Dissecting code step by step. Googling function names. Happy coding!